# Search profiles by city in Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to find a profile in a specific town or nation, but I just
found a way to get profiles by checking `locale` column in my Facebook
query. Is it possible to retrieve a user id and link with town and
other location information, but is it not possible to retrieve
profiles by town?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Facebook API, it is not possible to query by locale since it's not indexed (see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/ and look for column names with a * star).  According to the documentation the only columns you can search on with the API is uid, username, and name.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to query over the friends associated with the provided access token, you can do this FQL query:

```
    query = {}
    # first get friends which have provided a current location
    query['friends'] = "SELECT uid, name, current_location FROM user \
            WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) \
            AND current_location"
    # then get the latlongs corresponding to their current location
    query['latlong'] = "SELECT page_id, latitude, longitude FROM place \
            WHERE page_id IN (SELECT current_location.id FROM #friends)"
```

You can use this information to assign a latlong to each friend. The filtering must be done client-side ... I don't think there is another way.

NOTE: Of course this needs the `friends_location` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph API, you can search profiles using text place names like so:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=new%20york&type=user&access_token=???

(Replace ??? with your current access_token.)

Not clear to me exactly what profile text is matched against, so you may end up finding people that have a name similar to your search query or that are just talking about a place.  Best to check the users specified location as a second filter.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Queries of that kind definitely search 'hometown' so be wary of the results you get and be sure to check that the profile 'location' is what you want.